# How do I store projects that share a common shared driver on Git

Tags: eclipse, git, repository

I'd like to create Git repositories for some of my existing STM32 embedded C projects that I'm developing with Eclipse.
Currently I have two separate projects in their own folders, and a common folder containing ST's official STM32 Cube peripheral drivers (.c and .h) files that both projects use.
The driver folder shouldn't change (except when new versions are released) but the project files will be edited as I develop them.
How should I place them on Git? Should I:

1. Have three repos (one for each project and another for the drivers)?
2. Have two repos and change my project structure to place the drivers with both projects?
3. Something else?

The first option seems OK, but if I don't clone both the project and driver repos, and do them to specific locations, I can't see how I would configure Eclipse properly.
The second seems more hassle free but redundant (it won't be as easy to update all projects to use new drivers as they are released, and it will use more server space).

EDIT: Just to clarify, I'm not using the STM32CubeMX software. I'm simply using the STM32CubeF4 peripheral drivers, which are basically just embedded C .c/.h source/header files for the chip's internal peripherals (and possibly a few .lib library files for DSP calculations). See the "download" button at the bottom of this page for the .zip archive (current version is 1.4.0): http://www.st.com/web/en/catalog/tools/PF259243

Comment: Are you using CubeMX to generate the HAL layers and periph initialisation code? I also use it for several developments and I tend to keep them completely separately so I can upgrade CubeMX on each project separately.

Comment: Currently I'm not using the CubeMX software at all. I write all my own initialisation code (and their driver templates). I use Ubuntu and I'm not sure if there is a version of CubeMX for Linux anyway.

Comment: Here's what I've done:
1. Create two repositories; one for the project and one for the drivers
2. Create a submodule within the project repository that links to the driver repository.
3. Within Eclipse, I have had to exclude many of the driver repositories from the build process; otherwise Eclipse tries to compile every source file within the driver directory (the submodule) which causes issues since it contains many different files that I'm not using.

There must be a better way of linking directories in Eclipse that references relative to the workspace, not the file-system. For now it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a common driver in several other repos, it looks like a job for git submodules.

You have three separate repos, for example on your server, and both projects include the driver code as a submodule. What is stored in each project repo is:

- an *URL* to the driver repo (on your server)
- which *commit* of the driver repo is to be used
- the *path* where to put the driver clone, relative to the project repo

After cloning a project repo, you run `git submodule update --init`, and the repo at *URL* is cloned into the relative *path*, and its *commit* is checked out.

```
git submodule add --name <driver> /server/src/driver.git driver
```

(`/server/src/driver.git` is *URL*, `driver` is *path*. `<driver>` is just an optional reference to ease future work with submodules. Don't use it if it is the same as *path*)

---

git submodules feel a bit cumbersome at first. For example, cloning or checking out commits in the parent (project) repo does not make the submodules working files up to date. You have to manually `git submodule update` for that.

You will end up with two clones of your driver, one in each project's working files structure. But this is not really redundant, as they are clones of a common driver repo on your server.

For every update of your driver, you push the driver changes to your server. To update to the latest driver version in another project, you go to that project's submodule, do the usual `git push` (you might be in detached state, in which case you need to checkout `master` first). The update will show up in the project's (not the submodule's) `git status`, which will tell you "New commits" in the driver submodule. What has changed is which SHA1 is checked out in your submodule; commit the changes in the project will only update which submodule commit is to be checked out.

Comment: The OP's question is specifically about tracking code generated by CubeMX. Those drivers are constantly changing 1) by ST whenever they publish a new version and 2) by the user himself when changing code generation settings (like adding a new middleware component). It doesn't make sense to handle that code in a standalone repository IMO.

Comment: Ok, I don't know about CubeMX. If ST publishes new versions by just sending new files, I would still maintain a repo with these versions. That way the project's old commits would still use the same (old) version of the driver as when they were created. And about code generation settings, don't you think that changes in such settings are part of project progress, and should be versioned? OP seemed to want to put the driver code at a fixed location on the file system, and refer to that from the projects, so I assumed the driver did not change much while working on a project.

Comment: Yes, there is a CubeMX project description file which contains pin assignments, middleware components, GPIO settings, timers.. etc, which is then used to generate the code. I agree that project file should definately be versioned, I was not suggesting otherwise. As for submodules and versioning the generated code, I find it more manageable to treat everything in the same worktree (I'm not avoiding  submodules as I use them daily on other types of devs). I find that there are too many specifities of each project to capitalize on anything that's generated (assuming the OP is using CubeMX).

Comment: by the way the reason I'm commenting is that I'm still looking for an ideal way to handle source control on CubeMX :)